# Cause of "The Oauth identity of this script has been deleted" error message

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth

I've got a problem on some script I'm working on and I've got a error message like :

[image: The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted or disabled. This may be due to a Terms of Service violation.]

Which means :

> The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted or disabled. This
>   may be due to a Terms of Service violation.

I've see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled) that gave me a solution to resolve the problem.

My question is: how to avoid this kind of problem ? 
Does my script got a problem ? Does my script was automatically strike for some reason ? 
Looking at my research, all the people who've got the problem find a solution, but never find the cause of the problem.

Does anyone have some experience with this error message ?

Thank you.

Edit: The problem occur when user already review the permissions, not on permissions review. Thanks Zig to point that.

Comment: Can you post your code? THat may help figuring out why this happened

Comment: I don't think the problem came from the code, since it's working when I delete the project and create a new one with the same code. However, I'll put a sample of code when I finished to remove all the critical informations (since it's for a working purpose).

Comment: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644464

Comment: Thanks Zig for the link. But I didn't see the how it's related to my case ? I've no problem to put some permissions, the issue occur for people who already review the permissions (I should have mention that earlier).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918

Comment: you bring a interesting point on this topic. I'll be carefull on your answer next time the error show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Frank M. was right on his answer at [OAuth Error - script deleted or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled)

> This seems to fix the problem, but in fact it does not.
>
> The problem is related to the cloud project bound to the script, The
>   reason turned out to be that the TOS for Cloud projects changed and
>   that the user has to acknowledge this. If that does not happen then
>   after some time the whole shebang is disabled and you get the error
>   message.
>
> (This is why a copy seems to work: it works until some Google bot
>   notices that it is bound to a project without TOS acknowledgement and
>   then it disables it.)
>
> The solution: - open the script - click Resources > Cloud Platform
>   project - click on the bound project.
>
> This will open up the Cloud console and also show the popup for you to
>   acknowledge the new TOS. If you agree to this, you're set and your
>   script works again.
>
> Note: it seems that you need to do this only once for the Cloud
>   environment. So if you have several scripts then you need to do this
>   for one script only. Or access the Cloud environment directly and
>   acknowledge the new TOS.
>
> Note: even if you though your script is not bound to a Cloud project,
>   trust me... it is. If you do not bind it yourself, then it is bound to
>   a default project specific to that script.
>
> Hope this helps.

Even if the script doesn't work immediatly after accepting the new TOS, he work about 30 minutes after, as he suppose to work.