# Google Spreadsheet, getting error when running any script (even tutorial ones)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new to scripting, and I wanted to get a very simple script on google spreadsheets to create a column of random numbers between 1 and 150 odd every time I trigger it.

The issue is no matter what I put in the script box to actually run, it always comes up with:

The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted or disabled. This may be due to a Terms of Service violation.

After some googling I figured the issue was to do with authentication of the script, but even when I run the following tutorial script I get the same error:

```
function createAndSendDocument() {
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');

  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');

  // Get the URL of the document.
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  // Get the email address of the active user - that's you.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Get the name of the document to use as an email subject line.
  var subject = doc.getName();

  // Append a new string to the "url" variable to use as an email body.
  var body = 'Link to your doc: ' + url;

  // Send yourself an email with a link to the document.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: its a google bug.

Comment: Hi Zig! Do you know any way to circumvent it? Or alternatively do you know any way to make a function that will generate a random number that doesn't recalculate every edit? Thanks!

Comment: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644464

Comment: Thanks!! I've found a work around in the mean time. I just created a copy of the sheet and i'm using that instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Zig Mandel- its a bug

Here is a random number script that may help you.

```js
function ranNum() {
   // assume the array starts in A1 and runs down colA
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

   // getValues() returns an array
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  
  var num = "";
  num += Math.floor(Math.random() * 150 + 1);
 

  // Loop through every element in the range
  for(var j in range) {
    if(range[j].toString() == num) {
      Logger.log('matched');
    } else {

      // Write one code to the next line and stop the loop
      sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow()+1), 1).setValue(num);
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply! I tried running this code but got the error: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 6, file "Code").  Can you tell me where I need to add the range and other stuff?

Comment: Try this script I just edited- it is more specific for your needs. make sure there is a header or something in A1 Cell

Comment: It's almost working now! It only generates one number at a time though. Is it possible to make it run through a set amount of numbers at a time? Also is it possible to change which range it generates the numbers in (I want to make it generate the numbers on a different sheet if possible.) Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Just to elaborate, when I trigger the script I want it to generate a bunch of numbers over a range like J3:J153. When I run it again it will replace these numbers at range J3:J153 with new randomly generated numbers. This range will be on a different sheet to the active one. Thanks again!!