# Google Apps Script - OAuth Error

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, google-oauth

I am getting this error when I run a script from Google Apps Script:

> The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted or disabled. This may be due to a Terms of Service violation.

I have deleted and recreated the project and it works for a while but then the error re-occurs. I have also checked the bound project but there are no new Terms of Service agreements for me to acknowledge/accept (tried all the proposed solutions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled)).

Is there any way to get more details on what could be causing this issue or any other suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OAuth Error - script deleted or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled)

Comment: I linked to that post, it's the same error and I've tried all the solutions but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Its still a duplicate.  You will have to wait until you have the reputation to comment on that question and request additional help.