# The OAuth Error. Cannot solve TOS Violation

Tags: google-apps-script

I get an error "The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted or disabled. This may be due to a Terms of Service violation" whenever I try to execute a script that gives me daily updates from my calendar into a spreadsheet.

I have searched for solutions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled)

Thread that suggests "The solution: - open the script - click Resources > Cloud Platform project - click on the bound project" and then I will be able to accept the new TOS.

When I look at my menus, "Resources" only gives me dropdowns for Libraries and Advanced Google Services. This is a script and isn't tied to a Cloud project.

What would you suggest I do to overcome this issue? (For reference, I believe the issue started appearing in April 2018).

Comment: Are you in an organization? (Business / School)  Do you have a paid GSuite account?  Or is your account a free/consumer account?

Comment: All scripts *are* tied to a Google Cloud project - though the project is usually a private one. You can generally access it via the "Advanced Google Services" menu option.

Comment: @SandyGood I just have a consumer account otherwise I would try using GoogleSupport

Comment: @tehhowch Advanced Google Services just show me services I can tie into. The only active services on this project are DriveAPI and Gmail API. When I look at the Cloud Console it shows that I have no projects but forgive me if I am being naive.

Comment: I am also using a consumer account, with a script that I just created, and the Advanced Google Services menu opens this [image](https://i.imgur.com/qRmSFJK.png), and clicking the "Google API Console" takes me to the appropriate Cloud Console project.

Comment: @tehhowch I have tried that and it takes me to a "Failed to Load" page and I am not sure why. I have not removed / deleted any projects