# Cloud Platform project missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I have simillar situation to [OAuth Error - script deleted or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled) , but I don't have an option "Cloud Platform project" in Resources menu. Maybe this is because this spreadsheed wasn't created by me but still (person that created this doc is not in our company). So how I could fix this error or how I could take ownership of doc?

Comment: I've checked th ownership. I'm owner of doc. But maybe not an owner of CP project? How I can check it?

Comment: Is it in a Team Drive?

Comment: No, but it said that it's on my disk. Sorry if I couldn't give more complex info all this drive related stuff is conterintuitive to me.

Comment: You need to contact your admin to provide access to your GCP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by making a copy of the script.

- File > Make a Copy

It also solves your issue with the OAuth identity error.

Comment: Yes, but this is a library and used in dosens of other sheets. If I make a copy than I need to reimport this library in that sheets too. And this could be a problem.