# Startup Error "Retrieving Add-On Configuration"

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have been working on a google app scripts project for a couple of weeks now. It is a Google Data Studio Connector that works with Google and Facebook APIs to input data from Facebook to Data Studio.

I was working with the "Advanced google services" trying to add Google's URL shrinker(before reading that they were depreciating it.)

I tried a deployment after removing the service and now I am getting a "There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration." with a "REFRESH CONFIGURATION" button beside it. I feel like I altered some setting while messing with the API settings to break something in the deployment. I know it's on Google's side as copying the code into another apps-script project works fine.

Let me know if anyone else has encountered this error.

Comment: You may want to check this [page](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/README.md) which contains open source content for Google Data Studio. Try to run through the README with your personal gmail account and make sure both `main.js` and `appsscript.json` get copied over.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the manifest for the connector still includes the URL shortner servicer.
2. Remove authorization for the connector by going to Data Studio > Data Sources > (+) > (⋮) for your connector > remove access. Then authorize it again.
3. If you still get the error, then the issue might be with your `isAuthValid` / `isAdminUser` functions. (Assuming the connector works if you simply copy the Apps script project)

Comment: I followed the first two steps. Didn't find anything odd in manifest. Removed authorization in Data Sources. isAdminUser looked fine, but when I run isAuthValid it throws: "The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted"

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270918/oauth-error-script-deleted-or-disabled) but I do not get a TOS popup when I enter the Google Cloud Platform

Comment: And the connector work fine if you simply copy the Apps Script Project?

Comment: Yes it seems to work fine if I copy it on the account I have the other on. However accessing the copied project on my personal account, it says I 'no longer have access to the underlying data set'

Comment: It is difficult to figure out what the problem is here since you are getting different errors from different places. I would suggest trying to isolate the problem by trying different parts of the connector.